# Disallow vbNewLine When First Line Of Textbox is Empty

Tags: vb.net

Recently, I've been trying to get my program to enable a combo box with the following code. Keep in mind the textbox is multi-line enabled.

```
If TextBox1.Text.Count > 1 Then
ComboBox1.Enabled = True
End If
```

The one problem is that when you press enter without any text on the first line in the textbox, then type, it does not enable it. Any way to fix this w/out using a RichTextBox?

Basically I want do disallow a new line when first line is empty.

I've tried.

```
If TextBox1.Text = 0 Then
If vbNewLine = vbTrue Then
SendKeys.Send("{BS}")
End If
End If
```

Comment: There is no *Count*. It is `TextBox1.Text.Length`

Comment: you should use `Option Strict` (always), `If TextBox1.Text = 0` is nearly nonsense @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε, I think they are picking up the `Count` extension

Comment: @Plutonix Forgot *System.Linq*. nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for a band-aid, fix the real problem instead:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    ComboBox1.Enabled = TextBox1.Lines.Count > 0
End Sub
```

You can make the band-aid work too:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If TextBox1.Text = String.Empty And e.KeyChar = ChrW(13) Then e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, never knew you can do that!